# How to add a timestamp to Firebase via console?

Tags: firebase, date, firebase-realtime-database

```
-order
    -amount: 125
    -date: 13/11/2019
    -id: "SAV-00000001"
```

I am trying to add some data, something similar to above. I want the `date` field to be stored as a date object so that when I query it I can order by date.

When I add a date it's being stored as a string. Is there a way to make sure that it's stored as a date object instead?

Note: The questions I have found talk about how to add a date programmatically, but I'm trying to find out how to add it manually via the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there is no "date" type provided by Realtime Database.  You'll have to choose your own format for dates, and those will usually be a string or a number.

Second, the Firebase console doesn't have a field editor for date-related strings or numbers.  If you need a string or number, you're going to have to just type that yourself into the console, or create your own tool to make that easier.